# How could I make this word matching algo more efficient python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, edx

There is a dictionary `d` of letters and frequencies which represents a hand in a game similar to scrabble. If the letters in `word` are contained within `d` then the frequencies are changed or the letter is removed (if the value == 0) and the function `update` returns `True`, otherwise `d` is unchanged and the function returns `False':

```
d = {'a': 1, 'p': 2, 'c': 1, }

dCopy = d.copy()

matching_lets = 0


def update():

    for let in word:
        if not let in dCopy:
            return False
        else:
            if dCopy[let] == 1:
                del dCopy[let]
            else: 
                dCopy[let] -= 1
    d = dCopy
    return True 

word = 'pap'
print update()
```

This is part of problem set 5 from the EDX course MITx 6.00.1, Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python

Comment: i think instead of `return false` in first for loop must  be changed to `continue` and use a flag to check is `d` manipulated or not in order to return `false` if not

Comment: `d = dCopy` is not going to do anything unless you declare in `update()` that `d` is global. You would be better off using returns and arguments and getting rid of your global variables.

Answer (score 1):

**There's no faster solution** in Python, given your question. `dict()` is same as a `hashmap` and so your `update` function has `O(|word_length| + |dict_length|)` average case complexity where `word_length` is the number of characters in the given word and `dict_length` is the number of key-value pairs in your dict.

Note: @khelwood is correct about `d = dCopy`. Figure out how to solve that problem yourself.